# How to fix win32console message in rake test output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-test

I'm currently trying to learn Ruby on Rails on **Windows 10**.

I'm following the excellent [railstutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/).

However, I'm getting bugged by the 'gem install win32console' message (and lack of colour) appearing when I run `rake test`. How can I fix this?

### Sample output:

```
$ bundle exec rake test
ansi: 'gem install win32console' to use color on Windows
Started

  3/3: [===================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.35885s
3 tests, 6 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

### My setup:

Base: [Ruby 2.2 Rails Installer for Windows](http://railsinstaller.org/en).
Running commands using **Git Bash**.
I also have the [minitest-reporters](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters) gem installed ([step 3.7.1 of tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-minitest_reporters)).

### What I've tried:

1. First I ran `gem install win32console` bu this had no effect, even though the gem is visible when I run `gem list`.
2. Then I saw [win32console is deprecated](https://github.com/luislavena/win32console) so I installed [ansicon](http://adoxa.altervista.org/ansicon/).
   This also had no effect. And it seems colours are supported on Windows 10 anyway.
   E.g. I can run the **Hello World** example `puts "\e[34mHello \e[31mWorld\e[0m"` found on [this blog](http://blog.mmediasys.com/2010/11/24/we-all-love-colors/) and it shows blue and red text, whether ansicon is installed or not.
   However, colours won't show up correctly in `rake test` output and I still get the warning.

Comment: Did you add it to your Gemfile?

Comment: Aah I didn't think of that! That probably should have fixed it. However, I actually then get an error message: rake aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.2/Console_ext . . .

Comment: I'm going to try rebuilding win32console as suggested by [this blog post](https://paulsperambulations.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/automated-testing-and-fixing-win32console/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray got it working!

In the end your comment [Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan) plus the suggestions on [Paul's Perambulations](https://paulsperambulations.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/automated-testing-and-fixing-win32console/) got me there.

### Steps taken, for anyone else stuck on this:

1. Download and unzip [win32console source](https://github.com/luislavena/win32console)
2. Install specific (older) versions of the dependencies:

   - `gem install rake -v 10.4.2`
   - `gem install rake-compiler -v 0.9.9` (this is current latest anyway)
   - `gem install hoe -v 3.7.0`
3. Run `rake _10.4.2_ gem` in the win32console source directory (to use correct version)
4. Run `gem install pkg/win32console-1.3.2.gem` (had to change version number and flip the slash around from original instructions)
5. Add `gem "win32console", '1.3.2'` to Gemfile
6. Go back to project directory and run `bundle install`
7. Finally run `bundle exec rake test` - the info message has disappeared *and* colours are showing correctly!